# I am getting an error that says: "No module named 'dominate.tags';" even though I have installed dominate

Tags: python, pip, python-module, modulenotfounderror

I am trying to run the demo program for the python module Dominate. It is supposed to create an html file using python code.
(python 3.6.13 from microsoft store)

```html
import dominate
from dominate.tags import *

doc = dominate.document(title='Dominate your HTML')

with doc.head:
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='style.css')
    script(type='text/javascript', src='script.js')

with doc:
    with div(id='header').add(ol()):
        for i in ['home', 'about', 'contact']:
            li(a(i.title(), href='/%s.html' % i))

    with div():
        attr(cls='body')
        p('Lorem ipsum..')

print(doc)
```

I ran 'pip install dominate' and it installed successfully.
When I try to run this code, it gives me the following error:
[image: error]

I tried to run 'pip install dominate.tags', but it says that there is no such module.

What could be the problem?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The PROBLEM is that you called your own file `dominate.py`.  When you do `import dominate`, it's importing your file again, not the module.  Change your file name.

Comment: I see. I will try changing that right away.

Comment: I think the code snippet for the editor only works for HTML/CSS/JavaScript. You should probably use the `{}` button for styling python code. Otherwise you get this whole "Run code snippet" thing that just prints the code as-is as if its one giant HTML text node.

Comment: and you can get syntax highlighting in your code sample if you use something like `\`\`\`python` and `\`\`\`` to wrap